# Where can I view the reasons my question was downvoted?

Tags: support, downvotes

I got downvotes on a question and would like to improve my asking technique.  Is there a way to view the downvote reasons?

Comment: Almost 3K and asking this?

Comment: Yep!  You can see the question in black and white.  I earned most of my rep quite some time ago, and am no expert on the machinations of this site.  That's what meta is for, right?

Comment: Just find it extremely surprising that you never voted anything, for example. It is not easy interacting for so long with the site and not be familiar with some of its basic features.

Comment: Also the fact that you didn't search for this first,  it's one of the most repeated questions here

Comment: I am actually glad I asked this, because I imagine the number of duplicates on meta probably equates to an eventual second look by the design team.  I think forcing reason-selection on downvotes should be looked at again.  And no, I don't care that you've all discussed it without me already.

Comment: @yivi Now that you mention it, I don't think I've ever downvoted a question, but I could have forgotten.  I do upvote both questions and answers occasionally.  When I have a criticism, I always comment, because I can't see the utility of a criticism which is not articulated.

Comment: @Epodax I do see now that there has been plenty of discussion on the topic.  I did skim through the autocomplete as I typed the question and looked for a good match, but I admit, I was plenty comfortable simply asking my question here, the community is so vibrant, a good discussion always ensues.  Asking a question is like starting a forum topic in the old days... and I'm not sure I'm discouraged to do so by the downvoting/duplicate marking/fun comments.  Asking a question is still the most powerful thing you can do here, short of delivering a killer answer.

Comment: @Marcus 'no, I don't care that you've all discussed it without me already', OK, you have something to add?  Something new to bring to a discussion that has already spanned a decade and has dozens of posts?  If not, are you are suggesting that other users do your diligent search work for you by copying answers and comments from previous posts?

Comment: @MartinJames I am suggesting this feature change.  I do realize it's been suggested and discussed previously and I see many people agreeing with me.  So, I do have something to add, it's my voice, and despite your attempts, the platform does not allow for you to silence me completely.  Keep trying though.

Comment: @Marcus So you're glad that you were intentionally abusive and pointlessly wasted people's time with your questions?  That...says a lot about the type of person that you are that you care so little about anyone else in the community.

Comment: @Servy Abusive is a little strong, no?  I think what I did was submitted a question.  You're acting like you were groped.

Comment: @Marcus You did something that you knew was wrong for your own benefit.  That's abusive.  That you don't care in the slightest, and have no empathy whatsoever for anyone else is honestly a much bigger deal than if it were simply a mistake.

Comment: @Servy I don't think I did anything wrong, just asked a question and followed it up with a feature request.  I'm ok with being a minority voice on the issue and not getting the feature, but my opinion doesn't change because of that.  You are free to ignore me, you know.

Comment: "And no, I don't care that you've all discussed it without me already." "I don't think I did anything wrong" "but my opinion doesn't change because of that." So, why do you even bother asking the question if you are neither interested in the existing answers, nor in the consensual agreement on the matter, and will not evolve your opinion on the matter? @Marcus

Comment: @Marcus You don't think there's anything wrong with asking a duplicate question, when you know it's been asked repeatedly, for the sole purpose of annoying people for having to see the same awful suggestion *yet again*?  You've specifically said that you know you shouldn't have done it, and yet you did it anyway.

Comment: @Servy  The word "shouldn't" appears once on this page, in your comment.  Please quote me if you're going to quote me, you can't quote yourself and attribute me.  _That's_ abusive.

Comment: @Marcus So you've acknowledged that you know that you shouldn't have done it, and don't care.  Not a meaningful different.  You still did a thing that you know is wrong because you wanted to, and don't care about anyone else, and have stated that you're glad that you were abusive because you think you benefited from your abuse.

Comment: @Servy I think the sun'll still come up tomorrow despite my deeply abusive behaviors on the keyboard, but we've ceased to be productive today, so I am going to move on.  Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 19):

You can see the reasons for when a downvote should be used by looking at the tooltip:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

Additionally, the help center is *full* of information on how to ask a good question, and all of the things you need to do when asking a question.  If you want further reading on how to improve your questions, many pages in the help center have links for further reading that you can look into, and there's tons of information all over meta on how to ask appropriate questions, if you want to learn more about what does and doesn't make for a good question.

Comment: Ok, got it.  I was under the impression that downvoters also selected a specific reason while downvoting.  That'd be great, by the way!

Comment: @Marcus They do!  The reason is, "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".  Or, if it's an answer, "This answer is not useful".

Comment: that's 3 specific reasons.  Which one was the intended reason?  That's my feature request.  (now tagging for feature-request....)

Comment: @Marcus Take the time to ensure that your question has *none* of those problems, rather than trying to only fix one of them.  Changing your question into a completely different question after getting an answer is not appropriate.  Additionally, requesting people explain their downvotes has been asked many thousands of times, so don't waste your and our time by suggesting it, just *do your research* before asking your question.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/